# Difference between listening of stream by StreamBuilder and regular listen method

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using `http` library in order to download an image.

```
final client = http.Client();
final _response = await client.send(http.Request('GET', Uri.parse("my_url")));
```

**Listening way 1: (listen method)**

```
int downloaded = 0;
_response.stream.listen((value) {
  // this gets called 82 times and I receive actual image size
  downloaded += value.length;
});
```

**Listening way 2: (StreamBuilder widget)**

```
int downloaded = 0;
StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
  stream: _response.stream,
  builder: (_, snapshot) {
    // this gets called 11 times and I receive around 1/10 actual image size
    if (snapshot.hasData) downloaded += snapshot.data.length;
    return Container();
  },
);
```

The question is why `StreamBuilder`'s `build()` method isn't getting called that often when new data arrives, it simply defeats the purpose of being used as a widget.

Answer (score 4):

`StreamBuilder` is basically better optimized to not rebuilt on every new snapshot. As [`StreamBuilder` documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) states:

> Widget rebuilding is scheduled by each interaction, using
>   State.setState, but is otherwise decoupled from the timing of the
>   stream. The builder is called at the discretion of the Flutter
>   pipeline, and will thus receive a timing-dependent sub-sequence of the
>   snapshots that represent the interaction with the stream.
>
> As an example, when interacting with a stream producing the integers 0
>   through 9, the builder may be called with any ordered sub-sequence of
>   the following snapshots that includes the last one (the one with
>   ConnectionState.done):
>
> - `new AsyncSnapshot<int>.withData(ConnectionState.waiting, null)`
> - `new AsyncSnapshot<int>.withData(ConnectionState.active, 0)`
> - `new AsyncSnapshot<int>.withData(ConnectionState.active, 1)`
> - ...
> - `new AsyncSnapshot<int>.withData(ConnectionState.active, 9)`
> - `new AsyncSnapshot<int>.withData(ConnectionState.done, 9)`
>
> The actual sequence of invocations of the builder depends on the relative timing of events produced by the stream and the build rate of the Flutter pipeline.